# Yii - Can't render static pages - index was not found error

Tags: yii

Trying to following this:
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/22/how-to-display-static-pages-in-yii/

In order to this to be perfectly clear to me.

Steps:

**1)**

On this theater controller we create a method called actions:

```
 public function actions() {
            return array(
                'region'=>array('class'=>'CViewAction')
            );
        }
```

**2)**

on app/view/theater/ we will create a new folder called "region" where our static pages should reside;

**3)**

We should then edit the menu like this ?

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu', 
                array('items'=>array(
                    array(
                        'label'=>'Specifc Theater A',
                        'url'=>array('theater/region/nomeofmyfilewithoutextension')
                    ),
                    array(
                      'label'=>'Specific Theater B',
                      'url'=>array('theater/region/nomeofmyfilewithoutextension')
                    ),

...
```

**4)**

In order to avoid a login page to appear:
On our theater controller we should allow on our
accessRules some access to "region";

I'm getting:

> The requested view "index" was not found.

Any help please?

Should we configure routes on config.php ?

Comment: Is the file there? Is Yii searching in the right place?

Comment: I don't know. Yes. I have a file inside `app/view/theater/region/myfile.php` and, on the menu I have: `'url'=>array('theater/region/myfile')`

Comment: `myfile` should be a parameter. It should be `url=>array('/theather/region', 'view'=>'myfile')`

Comment: @Örs - that was it. Can you please make it an answer. Thks.

Comment: Well, actually, as far as I can tell, we can setup all the code as related here BUT a "pages" folder SHOULD be present. I believe, we cannot do this using ANOTHER folder name without (at least) tweak the framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`myfile` should be an argument for the `view` parameter.

It should be `url=>array('/theather/region', 'view'=>'myfile')`

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the `pages` folder as instructed on that site:

```
/view/theater/pages/region.php
```

and you link to this page like

```
/theater/page/view/region
```